Style the excel file from html table React
I was coding with ReactJS and I wanted a button that let me download my html table from the page as a excel table. And I made it but whatever I try, I can't add style to the excel like text to be centred or background colors. the table have a lot of column and also some headers with 2 rows... so the style is needed to make the table clear in excel.
this is the function of the export button, it only create basic excel without even a table containing the data:
    const exportToExcel = () => {
        const htmlTable = document.getElementById('table');
        const wb = XLSX.utils.table_to_book(htmlTable);
        XLSX.writeFile(wb, "ventes.xlsx");
    };

and ofc I did import the modules, as I said it work but I don't know how to style it.
